# canvas fails to generate all images in loop

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am using a loop to generate some HTML tables, they are not overly large, within the loop I was executing some JS (I have tried JQuery and JavaScript) to create the table as an image. It is only a small loop of 35 tables, but about two thirds of the way through it just returns blank images. I wondered if this was a memory problem or DOM being incomplete probelm so I wrapped my statement in a `$(document).ready()` still the same problem. I used one of the people just on their own in my loop and they generated fine. I get no errors in the console. I have been manually doing the JQuery within the console and checking the generation.

```
html2canvas($('#kimberly-t'), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        $('#kimberly-t-canvas').html('<img src="'+data+'" alt="">');
        }
    });
```

for each person and they all work fine and then one just won't work and every subsequent attempt at creating the image from a new HTML table fails. I don't even know how to start with this as there are no errors

**Update Bounty**

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksdyeytg/7/) to demonstrate the problem. You can see the first 10 calls to the divs generate an image. If you uncomment the rest of the JS it will either generate blank canvases or crash the browser. I get no errors on my local machine from the PHP loop or the console when the browser doesn't crash either.

Comment: I'd suspect a CORS issue. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) Check that all your images are from your domain.

Comment: @GameAlchemist All the images I am trying to create are just HTML from within my own webpage though. Could that still cause an issue?

Comment: Do you observe this behavior in all browsers? Are the "blank images" actually blank as in the `src` contain a blank image?

Comment: @Prusse I do in Chrome and Firefox, Chrome seems to get further into the loop that Firefox though. The src tags are not blank no, they generate ok, but the image is blank

Comment: I will say there is some problem regarding the re-rendering event handling (as in some being lost or ignored). Could you share a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with a sample code?

Comment: @Prusse I can try and do this yes

Comment: @Prusse https://jsfiddle.net/ksdyeytg/6/ I had some trouble getting it to save properly. Here it is I think with the external resources in. I've commented out the JS after div10 so you can see the loop works, if you remove the comment out of the JS this loop will likely crash your browser or it will just load blank images.

Comment: Sorry I can't locate the source of the problem.

Comment: The problem might be because the later elements are too off-screen. https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/117

Comment: @approxiblue Possibly, but when I render the first 10 divs not all of them are on the screen to start with...

Comment: i noticed that at my side in `FF` browser generated images amount was `22` not `10` so it mean it is related to client side memory or something like that, i also created this jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ksdyeytg/9/ where i added delay `100ms` between each `htmltocanvas` call with loop but anyway it stoped to display image at `22-dth` image which means it is not relate to some browser generation speed or `DOM` im almost sure that it is some browser instance memory limit

Comment: @Armen Thanks Armen, got to 26 images on mine

Comment: @Jonny Was you testing on google chrome ? because in google chrome i also got 26, seems each browser has its own `UI` limit or so

Comment: A bit off topic but... Why do you need the images?

Comment: @Prusse These tables are just one section of a report that about 3-40 people will received individual reports. They are very data intensive, so the JS charts or tabulated data is saved as images and then pulled into a HTML template and converted to PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it work with some trick, here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ksdyeytg/12/

where the trick was that i'm exporting cavas images with `100ms` delay storing them in one `base64Images` array and then after `10s` delay displaying them

**Storing part**

```
setTimeout(function(index){

      html2canvas( $('#div'+index) , {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
              var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

              // Instead displauing images directly
              //$('#div'+index+'-canvas').html('<img src="' + data + '" alt="">');          
              // Storing images
              base64Images.push( {'index':index, 'data':data} );
            }
      });  
}, 100*i, i );
```

**Display part**

```
setTimeout(function(index){

    for( var i = 0; i < base64Images.length; i++){

        $('#div' +base64Images[i]['index']+ '-canvas').html(            
           '<img style="border: 5px solid red;" src="' +base64Images[i]['data']+ '" alt="">'
        );
    }
}, 10000 );
```

This is not working normally `other browsers`, if i change 100ms delay  to lower amount it stop working under `chrome` also it crashing, if i change to display images directly starting from 26'th table images are not displayed as in initial Jonnny's example so lets say this parameters are ideal only for this amount of table with that amount of data inside for this exact browser and PC ...

*I know that this is not 100% and normal solution but is at least some*

My idea about this issue is following it is related to some kind of browser js stack size limits which are responsible to work with `canvas` part somehow. One more note in this jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ksdyeytg/11/ when i read same html table and directly display it 30 times it normaly working it is working evan with 64 times display but after 64 it again starts to not display image, i also searched in google some documentation about limitations in this sphere but it was useless ...

**The main idea of this solution is to display such images portion by portion to not have leak of browser "some" cache**

Answer (score 1):

actually i cannot reproduce your bug on Chrome (stable & Canary) or Firefox!

I don't see a problem with your code besides that it's not wise to use so many canvas-nodes in one website. my notebook has 16 GB RAM and a fancy CPU, hence no problems here, but any normal computer would probably run into the problems you described.

On a side-note: you might wanna start using for-loops for such repetitive actions as seen in my version of your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ksdyeytg/14/

```
for(var i=1;i<=39;i++) {
  html2canvas($('#div'+i), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      $('#div'+i+'-canvas').html('<img src="' + data + '" alt="">');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to run your fiddle but it broke my browser. Agreed regarding the loops, it's more pseudo code than anything, but demonstrates the point :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your DOM manipulation affecting the html2canvas code (stack problems, messing with events, race conditions, I don't know).

Check https://jsfiddle.net/ksdyeytg/17/ (it is not a very pretty solution but it can render your 39 tables, didn't test with more).

Here I look one table at a time and render it with html2canvas and save the resulting dataurl to a helper array then after all tables are processed I display the images:

```
  var process_div = function(index) {
    var id = divs_to_process[index];
    //console.log('process_div ' + id);
    html2canvas($(id), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        //$(id + '-canvas').html('<img src="' + data + '" alt="">');
        imgs.push([id + '-canvas', data]);
        data = undefined;
        setTimeout(process_div_wrapper, 0);
      }
    });
  };
  var i = 0;
  var process_div_wrapper = function() {
    if (i < divs_to_process.length) {
      var id = divs_to_process[i];
      process_div(i);
      ++i;
    } else {
      for (var j = 0; j < imgs.length; ++j) {
        var e = imgs[j];
        //console.log('show img ' + e[0]);
        $(e[0]).html('<img src="' + e[1] + '" alt="">');
      }
      alert('done');
    }
  };
  setTimeout(process_div_wrapper, 1);
```